# Unix: Accessed Denied, and cannot delete file?

Tags: unix

I created a file by redirecting output and the created file cannot be touched. Upon using any commands (such as `paste`, `cut`, `rm`), it tells me access denied. When I try to delete it using ftp, it says there is no such file, but I clearly see the file. Upon typing `ll`, where it shows the permissions, it says head or paste instead of rwx.

What should I do?

Comment: post the output of "ls -la filename"

Answer (score 3):

You can remove a file only if you have write permission to the directory it resides in, after that you can try to `unlink` it.

Comment: That's at least weird, anyway: 1. root can override any and all permissions, 2. check if you're not using ACLs 3. Are you using a UNIX file system (ext, xfs, etc.)?

Comment: Root is not god on a mandatory access control system.

Comment: yes it's a very poor choice, but that was about your ability to delete files in directory you don't have write access to

Comment: @bemace: Test again — as long as only unix filesystem permissions are involved, you do need write permission on the directory and not on the file. Some ACL systems (but not Linux's, other than potentially changing who has write permission), and security policy systems such as SELinux, can affect this.

Comment: @symcbean: It's not a matter of mandatory vs. discretionary access system. You could have a MAC with a god user. SELinux restricts what root can do, but not *because* it provides mandatory access control.

Comment: @Gilles: seems you're right.  I did several tests before my original comment, but now it's working like you describe.  Wish I knew what I did different the first time.